# How to code with Spring data MongoDB for db.test.update({name:'abc'}, {$pull: {'child': {'age':10}}})

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, pull

From console, I can operate as db.test.update({name:'abc'}, {$pull: {'child': {'age':10}}}).

How to code with spring-data-mongodb in Java for this instruction?
I got mongoTemplate. I know I need to invoke Update.pull(). But I don't know the details.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4):

```
update.pull("child", new BasicDBObject("age", 10));

mongoOperation.updateMulti(query, update, collectionName);
```

Comment: BasicDBObject is not imported in spring-data-mongodb maven dependency. Right? Are you using the same maven dependency?

Comment: BasicDBObject should be available via spring data, it's from the underlying Java Driver that spring data uses.