# MongoTemplate pull subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

I need to pull a subdocument in MongoTemplate but cannot figure out how to do it.

My saved document is:

```
{
    "_id" : "FooUser",
    "_class" : "com.domain.User",
    "tests" : [ 
        {
            "variant" : {
                "_id" : "C",
                "probability" : "0.5"
            },
            "experiment" : {
                "$ref" : "experiment",
                "$id" : "MyExperiment2"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "variant" : {
                "_id" : "B",
                "probability" : "0.5"
            },
            "experiment" : {
                "$ref" : "experiment",
                "$id" : "MyExperiment1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to remove only the test that has MyExperiment1.
Executing the following command works:

```
db.user.update( {}, {$pull: { "tests":{"experiment.$id":"MyExperiment1"}}}, {multi: true} )
```

How should I write this using Spring MongoTemplate?

I have tried the following, but does not work:

```
this.mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(), new Update().pull("tests", "{\"experiment.$id\":\"MyExperiment1\"}"), "user");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems this works:

```
this.mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(),
        new Update().pull("tests", Query.query(Criteria.where("experiment.$id").is("MyExperiment1"))), USERS_COLLECTION_NAME);
```

Comment: cid="idvalue"                                                   this.mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(),
        new Update().pull("tests", Query.query(Criteria.where("experiment.$id").is(cid))), USERS_COLLECTION_NAME); It is matching result but not removing the element.    how to match string id value ObjectId in pull opration.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which worked fine for me is the use of a `BasicDBObject` into the `pull` method's `value` param.
See [How to code with Spring data MongoDB for db.test.update({name:'abc'}, {$pull: {'child': {'age':10}}})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140739/how-to-code-with-spring-data-mongodb-for-db-test-updatenameabc-pull)

Answer (score 0):

That's my solution:

#### Pulling child-field

```java
  public Mono<Project> DeleteCritTemplArray(String id, String country) {

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id")
                              .is(id));

    Update update = new Update();
    update.pull("countryList", country);

    return template
         // findAndModify:
         // Find/modify/get the "new object" from a single operation.
         .findAndModify(
              query, update,
              new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true), Project.class
                       );

  }
```

#### Pulling child-Object

```java
 public Mono<ProjectChild> DeleteCritTemplChild(String id, String idch) {

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria
                           .where("_id")
                           .is(id)
                           .and("tasks._id")
                           .is(idch)
                     );

    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("tasks.$", null);

    return template
         // findAndModify:
         // Find/modify/get the "new object" from a single operation.
         .findAndModify(
              query, update,
              new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true), ProjectChild.class
                       );
  }
```